# How to stop Linux console output from being truncated when using Screen?

Tags: linux, centos, gnu-screen

**Overview**

I use Screen as an add-on to the Linux console so that I can have multiple screens and can run my server while doing additional tasks simultaneously.

**Issue**
The console output seems to be cut off if it gets beyond 25 lines, which is extremely irritating when an error is being thrown.

**Example**
As you can see in this picture below, there is much more space to be taken up in the console, but all of it is truncated. **Note**: On my main screen (the default screen for the console without adding any additional screen) I'm able to get the entire console to be filled up with text, which allows me to track my errors.

[image]

Comment: Are you sharing screen sessions (eg `screen -x`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

screen by default will use sizes which were current when screen was started. You can use `ctrl-a` `F` to resize to current terminal size. You can also use `ctrl-a` `[`  and arrow keys to scroll back in history.